# .NET API route error

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am trying to access the API via http://localhost:13489/api/User/TestUser/somestring but I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
  No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
  'http://localhost:13489/api/User/TestUser/dada'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the name 
'TestUser'.
</MessageDetail>
```

The method is as follows

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://i311061.venus.fhict.nl", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{ [Route("api/User/TestUser/{anystring}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string TestUser(string json)
    {
        return json;
    }
}
```

The route defined in the WebApiConfig.cs is as follows:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
 config.EnableCors();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Is the route defined in the wrong way or is there another issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should rename your {anystring} to {json} or string json to string anystring... in the end, your route placeholder should match the name of the method parameter.

Comment: @hellwd I tried what you said and the error changed to `Error>
<Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
</Error>`

Comment: Yeah, so your initial issue is solved :) New error you are getting is because you are not authenticated and your controller is decorated with [Authorize] attribute. Either obtain some cookie or token with your API or remove [Authorize] attribute while testing :)

Comment: @hellwd worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by renaming {anystring} to Json and removing the [Authorize]